# Customize Devise mail template path for the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email, devise, devise-confirmable

I am developing a rail application which include a rail engine. I use devise gem for account authentication. On one hand, I want to send confirmation_instruction mail with one template for main_app. On the other hand, I want to send confirmation_instruction mail with another template for rails engine. Both view use the same model "Account". Any ideas please help!

Comment: what's `rails engine` and `main_app` ?

Comment: Engines can be considered miniature applications that provide functionality to their host applications(main_app). Host applications can have many rails engines.

Comment: your use case is unclear , why would anyone use model from main app in rails engine functionality ?

Comment: because the logic is the same. only view is different. For example, desktop view and mobile view. Both have the same logic but different layout. Mobile view is rails engines, desktop view is main app.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new layout as you like called 'foo.html.erb'

In the main controller add the following:

```
layout "foo", :only => [ :index, :show ]
```

You can specify the layout for a specific action using:

```
def new 
 render(:layout => "layouts/application")
end
```

Define another layout for different action in a controller. It might be that adding another

```
layout "standard", :only => [ :new, :edit ]
```

might work...

and also try this way:-

```
class MyController < ApplicationController

 def foo
   @model = Bar.first
   respond_to do |format|
    format.html {render :layout => 'application'}
    format.html.phone {render :layout => 'phone'}
    format.html.tablet {render :layout => 'tablet'}
   end
 end

end
```

**In Rails 4.1 it is recently include** :-

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 before_action :detect_device_variant

 private

  def detect_device_variant
    case request.user_agent
    when /iPad/i
      request.variant = :tablet
    when /iPhone/i
      request.variant = :phone
    end
  end
end

class PostController < ApplicationController
 def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json
    format.html               # /app/views/posts/show.html.erb
    format.html.phone         # /app/views/posts/show.html+phone.erb
    format.html.tablet do
      @show_edit_link = false
    end
  end
 end
end
```